# Работа с элементом, который вложен в другой

Tags: jquery

Как работать с элементами, которые находятся внутри другого элемента?

К примеру есть ссылка:

```
<a>
<svg></svg>
</a>
```

При клике на ссылку я могу получить значения атрибутов и работать с данными самой ссылки **`<a>`**, а как работать с элементами, которые находятся в самой ссылке,  в данном случае необходимо выполнить `attr("style", "fill:#ff5e3a")` для **`<svg>`** при клике на ссылку?

Comment: `$("a").find("svg").attr("style", "fill:#ff5e3a")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click','a', (event) => {
  $(event.currentTarget).children('svg').css('background', '#ff5e3a');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a>AAA<svg></svg>BBB</a>
```